# TaskList of GitHub Flavored Markdown doesnt support ordered lists

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I noticed that there is a way to add tasklist in GFM, as mentioned in their blogpost here, https://github.com/blog/1375-task-lists-in-gfm-issues-pulls-comments

However it doesnt show any examples for task list for a ordered list. Is it supported? If so, can somebody share an example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's not supported. You can write an ordered list of checkboxes like this:

```
1. [ ] Foo
2. [ ] Bar
```

It renders as an ordered list in HTML (`<ol>`), but their stylesheet removes the numbers.

So while you can express the list as an ordered list, you would need your own stylesheet to render it as such.

Comment: This is an old post and there are likely much better styles for this but in my case adding a rule on `li` for `list-style: unset !important;` and `padding-left: 25px;` worked well

Comment: @davidk Can you specify this rule in the markdown itself?

Answer (score 4):

Note: since the introduction of **[nested task list](https://github.com/blog/1841-nested-task-lists)** (May 2014), numbered task list are still not supported, even though the following would still be rendered with `<ol>` elements:

```
1. [ ] Figure out wormholes
  1. [ ] Call @arfon
  2. [ ] Research ([docs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormhole#Time_travel))
  3. [ ] Build prototype #15
  4. [ ] Test run #43 @world-domination/time-travel
2. [ ] ...?
3. [ ] Profit!
```

And that would give:

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/182/2975762/9aedfb04-db98-11e3-9946-23e06671061f.png]

As in:

```
<ol class="task-list added">

    <li class="task-list-item">
        <input class="task-list-item-checkbox" type="checkbox" disabled=""></input>
        <label></label>

         Figure out wormholes 

        <ol class="task-list">
            <li class="task-list-item"></li>
            <li class="task-list-item"></li>
            <li class="task-list-item"></li>
            <li class="task-list-item"></li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="task-list-item"></li>
    <li class="task-list-item"></li>

</ol>
```